# how to increase maxRequestPerHost in okhttp

Tags: java, okhttp

We are using apollo java client for consuming graphQL service which internally uses okhttp (3.12.11)

We are using singleton instances of both apollo client and okhttpclient

The issue we are facing is the above code is bring run in an multi threaded environment and in visual VM I could see okhttp is executing only 5 parallel request's

We are not using aysnc feature . We have tried below mentioned and none of them worked

```
1. We have used dipatcher.setMaxRequest(30) / setMaxRequestPerHost(30)
2. We have also used new ConnectionPool(30,5,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

Can some one please tell me how to increase the limit of parallel request's in okhttp ?

**Update 1-:**
I have tried with 10 thread and still I could see okhttp is using only 5 threads

Could someone please help ?

Comment: How many threads are you using?

Comment: We are using 5 threads and using default connection pool of okhttp

Answer (score 0):

Configure OkHttp’s Dispatcher. It has limits on **total concurrent calls** and concurrent calls **per host**.

Comment: is there any relation with application thread(5)  ? I have set maxRequest and maxRequestperHost to  10 and 10 respectively but I still see only 5 in visual VM. Could you please help ?

Comment: Hi Jesse , do you mean we need to configure custom executor service and pass it to dispatcher ?

Comment: I mean maxRequests and maxRequestsPerHost. If that still doesn't work please create an executable test case that demonstrates the problem.